# How to untar a file

Tags: tar

I am trying to untar a file (new to Bash on Ubuntu on Windows), but it's showing an error. I have saved the file on the proper directory.

`drsonamani@LAPTOP-23SII9GR:/$ tar xvzf lammps-stable.tar.gz
tar (child): lammps-stable.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

Any help

Comment: Just looking at the error message, the file may not be where you expect.  `No such file or directory` is my clue.  So, the first step would be to verify the file is in fact there -- try something like `ls -lart *gz` to see if the file is in your local directory.  If not, you'll have to go find it first.

Comment: I tried its showing ``ls: cannot access '*gz': No such file or directory``

Comment: Use `ls` or `ls -l` to get a list of files in the current directory. Is it there?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). This page is intended for programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is saying that, in your current directory (which I assume is your home directory, when you start your bash shell in default manner), there is no file such as lammps-stable.tar.gz.
To solve this, I will break the problem in two steps.

(1) First find where is the "lammps-stable.tar.gz"

(2) Use the full path (obtained in step 1) and give it to tar command

How to get these.
Folder structure in Ubuntu starts from "/" (also called root). All other folders are nested within it. Every user has a folder in "/home". Say the username is "singh", all the folders and files by default will be stored in "/home/singh" or somewhere nested within it. You can know your user name by typing "whoami" in the bash shell or to locate your current directory, you can type "pwd".

**(1)** If you have a fair idea where the "lammps-stable.tar.gz" might be then the search will be shortened otherwise it will take a long time to finish (alongwith many warnings of 'Permission Denied').

***(1-a)*** You have rough idea that the "lammps-stable.tar.gz" is in /home/singh/Documents, then you will say the following

```sh
   find "/home/singh/Document" -name "lammps-stable.tar.gz"
```

See the output of above command and let us call it step 1 result.

***(1-b)*** You don't have much idea, where it is but you are sure the file belongs to you (user = singh), then I would say the following. This might take long time.

```sh
   find "/home/singh/" -name "lammps-stable.tar.gz"
```

See the output of above command and let us call it step 1 result

***(1-c)*** You don't any idea, where it is but you are sure the file is somewhere on the computer, then I would say the following. This might take long time.

```sh
   find "/" -name "lammps-stable.tar.gz"
```

See the output of above command and let us call it step 1 result

**(2)** Now using the result of Step1, just copy the path (let's say it is /MyFullPathToTheTarGZfile), then do the following.

```sh
tar xvzf /MyFullPathToTheTarGZfile
```

All the best.

Answer (score -1):

I usually use this command to extract the tar.gz to the same directory:

```
tar -zxvf lammps-stable.tar.gz
```

You should run this command on the directory where the file is located. Otherwise the command won't be able to find (you will get no such file error).  Try it to see if it works.

Comment: try: tar -C ./ -xzf lammps-stable.tar.gz   (for more such useful commands to unzip see -> http://www.tech-ladder.com/2022/07/tech-laddercom-articles-and-snippets.html